# Strategy to reduce pasting code over and over

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel, I have a sidebar that displays a users daily entry count

In each controller function, i'm having to have the following since the sidebar is always shown.

```
$data['entry_count_today'] = Data_group1::TodayCount('group1', Auth::user()->id)->count();
```

There has got to be a better way to have this available throughout the controller than to just paste this in every function.

Suggestions?

Comment: Make it available through a composer. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom middleware and share data to any view you wish.

```
php artisan make:middleware Sidebar
```

In your generated middleware handle function add this:

```
$data['entry_count_today'] = Data_group1::TodayCount('group1', Auth::user()->id)->count();

\View::share('data', $data);

return $next($request);
```

Add the middleware to $routeMiddleware array in Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'sidebar' => \App\Http\Middleware\Sidebar::class,
    ...
];
```

And finally in your routes folder web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['sidebar']], function(){
//add routes you want the data to be passed on
});
```

And the in the view you can access the data with: `$data['entry_count_today']`